# New line and tabs being added to my string in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, angular-material

**I have the following div in my html:**

```
<div flex style="white-space:pre-wrap;">
    {{c.display}}
</div>
```

`c.display` **is set like so:**

```
$scope.c.display = "foo\nbar\n\tfoobar";
```

**The output looks like so:**

[image]

**The html source looks like this:**

[image]

**If I change the source on Chrome using the dev tools to this:**

[image]

**I get what I wanted the whole time, which is this:**

[image]

So, why is this happening and how can I make it stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about removing white-space from within the div?

```
<div flex style="white-space:pre-wrap;">{{c.display}}</div>
```

Comment: Well, that works. I for some reason thought that the white space around the `{{c.display}}` didn't have an effect.

Comment: CSS style directive `"white-space:pre-wrap"` preserves white-space within the element.  That includes everything before and after the data binding `{{c.display}}`.